# Shorter replace expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have this with several full stops afterwards, for which I can't use g modifier:

```
s/\.([^.]+)\./;\1;/
```

or

```
s/\./;/
s/\./;/
```

Can you think of something more elegant and simple?

I really didn't think it was important to provide any example. The search string could be anything but a full stop:

29.01.2002;21:50:10;Som.eo.ne;some.thi.ng;

Comment: What should it match ?

Comment: you need to provide example search text and what you want it to match.

Comment: ok, your first expression matches `.jgsdlkaj.` and your other two expressions (which are exactly the same?) match `.`.  What are you trying to match?  What exactly is your question? Give examples.  please learn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not simpler, but may help in case you don't know the number of dots.

```
substr($_,0,index($_,";"))=~s/[.]/;/g
```

But you can also you split of course.

Comment: Your expression looks awasome, except that I now have to find out what subst and index functions do. I was actually looking for something like s/\./;/ x2; which is somewhere between FIRST and ALL occurences of .

Comment: index function finds the index of the first occurrence of `;` and substr gets the part upto that location. are you trying to replace all occurrences of `.` upto the first `;`?

Comment: Yes, that would be the aim, up until the first semicolon. Or better still from 3 to 4 occurence of ;

Comment: Then perhaps using split makes more sense

Comment: Probably you are right. I was truly hoping for a miracle. Thank you very much any way!